# python k-means clustering text

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am trying to find an example to assist me to cluster some textual data I have. The data is in the form:

```
A,B,3
C,D,5
A,D,57
```

The two first entries are the members of a pair, the number is how often this pair occurs in the dataset. I have over 200,000 unique pairs.

Any tips? Thanks!!

Comment: What exactly is your question? What have you tried?

Comment: Pretty much just tried to find a piece of code that does something similar to what I am trying to do. All I find is code that clusters documents, not pairs. The thing is, the description/requirements I received might be erroneous. Thank you for answering!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Don't use k-means on such data.

It will not work.

What you have is a similarity matrix, not continuous vectors as needed for k-means. You can try hierarchical clustering (with a sparse similarity, *not* a distance; no, I won't write the code for you).

Comment: Thank you! I am by no means asking anybody to write me a code, but I was having trouble finding anything that was similar to what I am trying to do. This makes it clear why that is. Thank you.